# how to get hyper-v host processor info in guest machine

Tags: wmi, processor, hyper-v

My problem is in guest machine how to get hyper-v host processor info. I don't want to use wmi for it need close the host machine firewall. Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The Hyper-V API **is** WMI, so anything you do will ultimately call WMI.

The issue in your case is that there is no network path to the host or you've closed the port that that WMI remote invocations are made through.

The way XenServer gets around this problem is by creating a host isolated network.  Create an adapter on the host with slightly less rigourous firewall rules.  Add a NIC to the network on the guest so that it can make remote invocations.